# jQuery on() method not working for appended elements

Tags: jquery

I know I should use on() method for triggering appended elements and not use click(), so:

```
$('#change_profile_img').on('click', function(){
alert(1);           
});
```

so the above code is working fine on any elements unless the appended elements, for example, I'm appending:

```
$('.companylogo:first').append('<a id="change_profile_img" class="ic_change">CHANGE IMAGE</a>');
```

after it's appended, it's not working, but after a page refresh it works just fine.
Another thing that I should mention, I'm doing the append from a modal page, it appends the button and everything but I could not trigger it anymore...

I would appreciate any kind of help.
Thanks

Comment: there are 2, I tried to get rid of the second one, still not working! this is making me crazy

Comment: Can you copy your case at: http://jsfiddle.net/ I think it will help us understand better your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine for you:

```
$(".companylogo").on("click", "#change_profile_img", function() {
  alert(1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use it this way

```
$(document).on('click','#change_profile_img', function(){
    alert(1);           
});
```

**Update**

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VPhCE/)

you are missing `href` in `a` tag

Comment: not working yet, that's weird your code with $(document) make it not working at all, even after page refresh, I'm struggling with this for more than 3 hours

Comment: Have you added `href` to `<a id="change_profile_img" class="ic_change">CHANGE IMAGE</a>`?

Comment: I checked it on another page, your code is working as it is in jsFiddle, there is something wrong in my page, I guess it's because its appending from the modal is causing this, but the weird thing is that it append the buttons etc, but I could not trigger it... thanks anyway

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18656/discussion-between-behz4d-and-al0ne-evenings)

Comment: Do you need to place the listener so high on the DOM? I would think that placing it on the .companylogo element(s) would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try delegating the click event when appending the element like this.

```
$('.companylogo:first')
    .append('<a id="change_profile_img" class="ic_change">CHANGE IMAGE</a>')
    .delegate('#change_profile_img', 'click', function(){
        alert(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
function GetIt()
{ 
    $('#change_profile_img').on('click', function(){
        alert(1);           
    });
}
```

You may call **GetIt()** function on body onload and each append time.

Comment: I would not use this method. There is the potential to bind the click event to the element(s) more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it's not working on this page, but finally I solved it by clearing the question a little bit!
I put the appended elements on the page from the beginning, with the display='none', on the modal instead of appending them, I just show()ed them, and now everything is working out, thanks everyone